# Highcharts Scrollbar up arrow throws error on click

Tags: svg, highcharts, scrollbar

When clicking the up arrow on a highcharts xrange graph with a scrollbar on the yAxis (there is also one on the xAxis but it doesn't throw an error when i use it's arrow button) 
the error returned is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (highcharts.src.js:5182)
```

I haven't found anything specific on the internet about this error so far but if i do i will update this ticket

Might this have something to do with having an X and Y scrollbar ? 
I don't plan on using the button at all since we have implemented a listener for the trackpad/wheel - is there a way of removing the arrow button entirely (rather than make it transparent which i currently have implemented which includes an unsightly hover i can't get rid of)

If you can help me A) Remove/hide the button entirely B) listen for the click and throw away the event to avoid this error or C) fix whatever the underlying cause of this error is ... i'd greatly appreciate it

```
{
    'chart': {
      'renderTo': graphId,
      'type': 'xrange',
      'zoomType': 'xy',
      'panning': true,
      'panKey': 'shift',
      'marginRight': 40,
      'marginLeft': 150,
      'resetZoomButton': {
        'position': {
          'x': -150,
          'y': -10
        }
      }
    },
    'exporting': {
      'enabled': true,
      'buttons': {
        'enabled': true,
        'contextButton': {
          'enabled': false
        },
        'resetScopeButton': {
          'y': -10,
          'x': -25,
          'symbolX': 20,
          'symbolY': 20,
          'enabled': true,
          'onclick': context['LiAnalytics']['resetScopeButton'],
          'symbol': 'url(../images/refresh.png)'
        },
        'hourButton': {
          'enabled': true,
          'text': 'H',
          'y': -10,
          'x': -50,
          'onclick': context['LiAnalytics']['hourButton']
        },
        'dayButton': {
          'text': 'D',
          'y': -10,
          'x': -75,
          'enabled': endTS - startTS > 86400000,
          'onclick': context['LiAnalytics']['dayButton']
        },
        'weekButton': {
          'text': 'W',
          'y': -10,
          'x': -100,
          'enabled': endTS - startTS >= 604800000,
          'onclick': context['LiAnalytics']['weekButton']
        },
        'monthButton': {
          'text': 'M',
          'y': -10,
          'x': -125,
          'enabled': endTS - startTS >= 2419000000,
          'onclick': context['LiAnalytics']['monthButton']
        }
      }
    },
    'legend': {
      'enabled': false
    },
    'xAxis': {
      'type': 'datetime',
      'dateTimeLabelFormats': {
        ...
      },
      'events': {
        'setExtremes': new js.JsFunction.withThis(_handleRedraw)
      },
      'min': (endTS - startTS) > initialZoom ? endTS - initialZoom : startTS,
      'max': endTS,
      'scrollbar': {
        'enabled': true,
        'showFull': false,
        'barBackgroundColor': '#ccc',
        'barBorderRadius': 7,
        'barBorderWidth': 0,
        'buttonBorderWidth': 0,
        'buttonArrowColor': 'transparent',
        'buttonBackgroundColor': 'transparent',
        'rifleColor': 'transparent',
        'trackBackgroundColor': '#F3F3F3',
        'trackBorderColor': 'transparent',
        'height': 10,
        'minWidth': 25
      }
    },
    'yAxis': {
      'categories': agents,
      'min': 0,
      'max': agents.length < maxY ? agents.length - 1 : maxY,
      'scrollbar': { /* Why you throw err on click ? */
        'enabled': true,
        'showFull': false,
        'barBackgroundColor': '#ccc',
        'barBorderRadius': 7,
        'barBorderWidth': 0,
        'buttonBorderWidth': 0,
        'buttonArrowColor': 'transparent', /* Remove entirely ? */
        'buttonBackgroundColor': 'transparent',
        'rifleColor': 'transparent',
        'trackBackgroundColor': '#F3F3F3',
        'trackBorderColor': 'transparent',
        'height': 10,
        'minWidth': 25
      },
      'reversed': true,
      'tickmarkPlacement': 'on',
      'gridLineColor': 'transparent'
    },
    'plotOptions': {
      'series': {
        'animation': {
          'duration': 2000
        },
        'point': {
          'events': { /* can i do something similar for scrollbar? */
            'mouseOver': new js.JsFunction.withThis(_mouseOver),
            'mouseOut': new js.JsFunction.withThis(_mouseOut)
          }
        },
        'pointWidth': 20,
        'pointPlacement': 0,
        'minPointLength': 10,
        'borderRadius': 0
      }
    },
    'series': series,
    'tooltip': {
      ...
    }
  }
```

(C) Current code block

```
(function() {
    //internal functions
    function stopEvent(e) {
        if (e) {
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            if (e.stopPropagation) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
            e.cancelBubble = true;
        }
    }
    /* Wrap allows us to override the behavior of render while not interrupting the normal rendering procedure */
    Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Chart.prototype, 'render', function(proceed) {
        var chart = this;

        proceed.call(chart);
        /* When a chart has a scrollbar and is xrange our PM/UX has requested the touchpad be abled to control the scrollbar */
        if (chart.options['chart']['type'] === "xrange" && chart.options['yAxis'][0]['scrollbar']['enabled']) {
            // Add the mousewheel event
            Highcharts.addEvent(chart.container, document.onmousewheel === undefined ? 'DOMMouseScroll' : 'mousewheel', function (event) {

                var delta, diff, extr, newMax, newMin, step, axis = chart.yAxis[0];
                e = chart.pointer.normalize(event);
                // Firefox uses e.detail, WebKit and IE uses wheelDelta
                delta = e.detail || -(e.wheelDelta / 120);
                delta = delta < 0 ? 1 : -1;
                /* Up or Down */
                if (chart.isInsidePlot(e.chartX - chart.plotLeft, e.chartY - chart.plotTop)) {
                    extr = axis.getExtremes();
                    if (extr.dataMax !== extr.dataMin) {
                        diff = extr.max - extr.min;
                        step = diff / 5;
                        /* move by fifths */
                        step = step > 1 ? Math.ceil(step) : 1;
                        /* Min step is 1, Move by whole numbers */
                        step = step * delta;
                        /* Up/Down */
                        if (step > 0) {
                            /* UP */
                            if (extr.max + step > extr.dataMax) {
                                newMax = extr.dataMax;
                                newMin = extr.dataMax - diff;
                                /* Enforce window not getting too small */
                            } else {
                                newMin = extr.min + step;
                                newMax = extr.max + step;
                            }
                        } else {
                            /* DOWN */
                            if (extr.min + step < 0) {
                                newMin = 0;
                                newMax = diff;
                            } else {
                                newMin = extr.min + step;
                                newMax = extr.max + step;
                            }
                        }
                        axis.setExtremes(newMin, newMax, true, false);
                    }
                }
                stopEvent(event);
                return false;
            });
        }
    });

    Highcharts.Scrollbar.prototype.addEvents = function() {
        var chart = this;

        var buttonsOrder = chart.options.inverted ? [1, 0] : [0, 1],
            buttons = chart.scrollbarButtons,
            bar = chart.scrollbarGroup.element,
            track = chart.track.element,
            mouseDownHandler = chart.mouseDownHandler,
            mouseMoveHandler = chart.mouseMoveHandler,
            mouseUpHandler = chart.mouseUpHandler,
            _events;

        // Mouse events
        _events = [
            /*    [buttons[buttonsOrder[0]].element, 'click', this.buttonToMinClick],
                  [buttons[buttonsOrder[1]].element, 'click', this.buttonToMaxClick], */
            [track, 'click', this.trackClick],
            [bar, 'mousedown', mouseDownHandler],
            [bar.ownerDocument, 'mousemove', mouseMoveHandler],
            [bar.ownerDocument, 'mouseup', mouseUpHandler]
        ];

        // Touch events
        if (Highcharts.hasTouch) {
            _events.push(
                [bar, 'touchstart', mouseDownHandler], [bar.ownerDocument, 'touchmove', mouseMoveHandler], [bar.ownerDocument, 'touchend', mouseUpHandler]
            );
        }

        // Add them all
        _events.forEach(function(args) {
            Highcharts.addEvent.apply(null, args);
        });
        chart._events = _events;
    };
}());
```

EDIT: removed old details

Comment: Could you reproduce it in online code editor like jsfiddle?

Comment: I created a Js Fiddle w/ 2 scrollbars but no console log to catch the errors - is there a feature i'm missing ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/he1cbrxL/2/ is a jsfiddle w/ 2 scrollbars (my intuition as to the source) however they work & don't throw any errors

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/QfBX9jdVCeTY ^ does this help at all NOTE: xAxis scrollbar does not cause errors when dragged or arrow button used. yAxis does not throw when dragged but does when arrow button clicked

Comment: it could also do with the fact that i've wrapped the render method so that i can get the scrollbar to listen to trackpad events

Comment: Ok, so could you reproduce it with the wrapper? Try to use a debugger to find out where this error occurs exactly and why.

Comment: i've found where the error occurs in the highcharts code as shown by the screencast debugging and the first comment on this question - the 'click' event gets fired without a callback - that 'button' is being created as part of highcharts scrollbar create but somehow isn't given a click callback (|| something to do with 2 scrollbars colliding on callback bc same button id or some such) - i have no way that i know of to wrap that click event like i wrap the highcharts render to give it the ability to listen for trackpad events. If i could wrap it i would just make it a no-op

Comment: You can overwrite `Highcharts.Scrollbar.prototype.addEvents` method and there you will find _events array - get rid of events for buttons. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1j2voakh/1/

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for ! alright perfect i'll work on implementing that, i'm not super familiar with js syntax and even less so how Highcharts deals with wrappings/overwritting. we have a js file that wraps the render method for all charts (but only adds the listener for xrange) could you help me w/ syntax to override the Scrollbar.addEvents method into this code for a two birds one stone or lmk if i need to keep them separate (added code to question) - 1) should I add the override here or elsewhere 2) can i combine the two into 1 override (Highcharts listen for event vs scroll )

Comment: no dice on adding the block (B) bellow the first wrap - still catches click event and throws error - so weird since addEvents in stock.src.js has callbacks defined for each button (note the error itself references highcharts.src.js not stock.src.js could this be a smoking gun)

Comment: You have to wrap the B code block with IIFE. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9d60eg58/

Comment: @WojciechChmiel thanks for all the help - unfortunately what you have in the JS fiddle is exactly what i have and i still get the error when clicking - it doesn't blow anything up so i may just have to leave it but it sure is annoying

Comment: @WojciechChmiel added exact code block i'm running as (C)

Comment: Strange, because jsfiddle works perfectly fine. Are you sure these are the only changes?

Comment: yeah i'm sure, we were never able to replicate the error in jsfiddle though - it may have something to do with bundling all the other src.js files, at least that's my intuition

Comment: is there an alternative way @WojciechChmiel for us to debug this ?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel Just found some Shit ! the button that's throwing the error isn't the up arrow for the scrollbar like i thought it's the context button that i have disabled - not sure why it's even being added to the DOM when it's disabled but this give me the info to dig deeper and go solve that

Comment: found this out by reenabling the button and having it appear where the erstwhile mystery button was (that i thought was the arrow just transparent)

Comment: @WojciechChmiel jsfiddle that actually shows phantom button issue https://jsfiddle.net/km4yeqxb/

Comment: This issue is caused by options that are not listed in the `exporting.buttons` API like `exporting.buttons.resetScopeButton` and `exporting.buttons.enabled`. Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pk7a8ytc/.

Comment: sure but you should be able to disable the context button (remove it completely) but still have custom buttons with custom behavior - i did end up solving this problem by repurposing the contextButton to be the resetScopeButton (and leaving my other buttons as they are) - since the contextButton is enabled i avoid the phantom button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by trying to singularly disable the context button while including other custom buttons. The context button hung around as a phantom button that was overladed over the scrollbar up arrow causing the misdiagnosis during debugging.

Solution i ended up going up with was repurposing the context button by overriding the symbol/symbolX symoblY(to center symbol in button area)/onclick behavior

routed onclick to the resetScope behavior i was working toward
overrode the burger symbol with the png saved / decided on by UX